# Bash script in context menu

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running Debian with LXDE, I've just started to learn bash scripting. Is there a way to drag and drop a file (any file) onto a bash script file and make it so that the filename is placed into a variable in the script?
Or better yet: place the script into a context menu (like shell:sendto in Windows), and activate it by clicking on files with right mouse button (and choosing my script)?

Comment: this question should be asked on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you, I'll ask there then.